# how to make my epd python as my default python in ubuntu?

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, python-2.7, enthought

I recently installed epd python distribution in ubuntu. This got installed in the folder `/home/jai/Downloads/epd_free-7.3-2-rh5-x86_64`

Can you tell me how to make this python as my default python?

I get errors while running a test program (it seems my default python is different and it doesn't have numpy library, other libraries that come along epd python distribution.)

My test program is here: http://www.southampton.ac.uk/~fangohr/computing/download/python/tests/testall.py

Comment: Overlaying the platform's python is risky business. You risk system scripts or other applications failing if epd has a different version or mix of modules than the platform python. I don't know about debian/ubuntu, but this could be very hazardous on some distros like redhat/fedora. Have you tried python virtualenv? You create a separate python environment for your applications while leaving the system alone.

Answer (score 1):

Default python is the one found in /usr/bin directory with the name python. Making a symbolic link of :

```
ln -s /home/jai/Downloads/epd_free-7.3-2-rh5-x86_64 /usr/bin/python
```

Assuming that is the name of the python executable, not the installer. After you installed, use the path where you installed it. f.e `/home/iai/myNewPythonInstallation`

might do the trick.

Most likely default 2.7 python is occupying that name, so you need to remove that, or use another name like epdPython. Then running python scripts would happen with:

```
epdPython myscript.py
```

Comment: Replacing /usr/bin/python might be a bad idea, for the reasons @tdelaney gave in his comment on the question.

Comment: True, that's why I included the possibility of using another executable name.

Answer (score 1):

The "default" python depends on how you're invoking it.

On Ubuntu, python is normally installed as `/usr/bin/python` (not `/bin/python`) -- which may be a symbolic link.

If you invoke the `python` command, e.g.:

```
$ python myscript.py
```

it will use whichever `python` executable is in a directory that appears first in your `$PATH`.  You can modify your `$PATH`, either for your current shell:

```
export PATH="/some/dir:$PATH"
```

or for all future shells by updating your `$HOME/.bashrc`, `$HOME/.bash_profile`, or whatever.  `/usr/local/bin` is one common place to put system-specific executables, or `$HOME/bin` for user-specific executables.

If you want to execute the script itself, you'll need a [shebang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) as the first line of the script:

```
$ head -1 myscript.py
#!/usr/bin/python
$ ./myscript.py
...
```

You can edit the shebang to refer to whatever Python executable you want to use.

You *can* replace `/usr/bin/python` with your preferred Python executable, but that might cause unwanted side effects; existing Python scripts that assume `/usr/bin/python` is the default might break.

Another option is to change the shebang to:

```
 #!/usr/bin/env python
```

which lets you execute the script directly while still using whichever `python` is first in your `$PATH`.  This may or may not be a good idea; see [my answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/29620/10454) to [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/29608/10454) for further discussion.